# raster2pgsql does nothing

Tags: postgis, gdal, postgis-2.0, raster2pgsql

I try to load rasters through raster2pgsql. I try to call it through pgAdmin command line, but when I call any `raster2pgsql` command (even `raster2pgsql -G`), it does nothing, I just get another line to write more commands. No output, no time doing something. Non-gdal psql commands work as expected. `\raster2pgsql` leads to "invalid command" error. I am new to the command line and psql, so I'm stuck here.

I have PostgreSQL 9.3.4, PostGIS 2.1.3 and pgAdmin III 1.18.1 on WIndows XP 32 bit. I made sure that `raster2pgsql.exe` is in its place in `bin` folder, but I don't know of other ways to validate whether it is installed properly.

Comment: Launch the program from Windows command window when you are in the installation directory which is probably c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin. I believe you have already read http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-svn/using_raster.xml.html#RT_Raster_Loader

Comment: That's the old site.  New site is http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/using_raster_dataman.html#RT_Loading_Rasters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first mistake is trying to call it via pgAdmin command line.  Just call it from dos screen.

What you could do is create a batch file like

load_data.bat

Then put lines like folliowing in there and then run the bat file

```
SET PATH="%PATH%;c:\Program files\PostgresSQL\9.3\bin"
SET PGPORT=5432
SET PGHOST=localhost
SET PGUSER=postgres
SET PGPASSWORD=whatever
raster2pgsql -I -e -F -C -Y -s 26986 -t 500x500  dems/*.tif noaa | psql -d yourdb
pause
```

Putting a pause will allow you to see what happens

Comment: It works for me only if I navigate to the bin folder of my PostgreSQL installation, otherwise it classifies raster2pgsql as an unknown command. Anyway, it works.

Comment: Now it works; I have PGPATH variable containing the path to my PostgreSQL bin directory (it is on drive d on my PC), and then I changed the second-from-end row to: CALL %PGPATH%raster2pgsql...